# How to produce a build error if a certain file was found

Tags: shell, makefile

I want to generate a build error if one or more files matching a certain pattern are found in the current directory.

To illustrate, my make file target currently looks like this:

```
generate-java:
    swig -c++ -java interface.i
```

The `swig` utility generates Java classes for each C++ class it encounters in the C++ source code. However, if it encounters usage of a C++ class that for which no definition has been found it will generate a dummy class. The dummy class typically is named something like `SWIGTYPE_p_MyClass`.

If this situation occurs then I want to treat it as an error. So if a file is found that is named `SWIGTYPE_p*.java` or contains the string `SWIGTYPE_p` then I want the build to fail.

I think I need to change the build target to someting like this:

```
generate-java:
    swig -c++ -java interface.i
    find . -name "SWIGTYPE_p.*\.java" --> generate build error if found
    find . -name "*\.java" | xargs grep SWIGTYPE_p --> generate build error if found
```

I think I need to compose a command that returns an exit status different from zero in case the string is found. However, I don't know how to do this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `test` command of the shell to test whether the output of your `find` command is empty. This will emit a fail status (!=0) if find returns something.

```
generate-java:
        swig -c++ -java interface.i
        test -z "$(shell find -name 'SWIGTYPE_p.*\.java')"
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible ways could be to just count the files returned from `find` using `wc` and if the count is greater than zero call exit with the error number of your choice.
For instance your rule could be:

```
generate-java:    
    swig -c++ -java interface.i && \
    if [ `find ./ -iname "SWIGTYPE_p.*\.java" | wc -l` -gt 0 ];then   \
            echo "SWIGTYPE_p*.java found!!" && exit 3;        \
    fi
```

If there are any file found make will exit the error as `make: *** [generate-java] Error 3`
You can have the exit error code as the number of your choice and echo statement is again a matter of your choice.